# Cognos dpr-err-2079 firewall security rejection

Tags: firewall, cognos

I am using Cognos 10.2.1. This is working fine with the following Cognos firewall settings.
Enable CAF Validation: True.
Is third party XSS checking enabled? False.

When I change Is third party XSS checking enabled? to True I get the following error:
dpr-err-2079 firewall security rejection. your request was rejected by the security firewall

If I reset back to false the problem goes away.
We are connection to the reports via the Gateway URI:
https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com:443/cognos10/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi

Any thoughts please.

Comment: Do you actually have a third party XSS tool?  With that set to `False`, Cognos does it's own XSS checking.  [Clicky!](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.1.0.doc%2Finst_cr_winux_id20987cnfg_CAF.html)

Comment: Why do you need to enable the firrwall? In all my installation I am turning off the Cognos internal firewall off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We re-installed Cognos and set the Firewall as required and this time it worked.